# Adoption of Protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols, covariance, contravariance

I'm struggling to understand why I'm getting a particular error in Swift.

Specifically, If I have a protocol 'X' which defines a property that must adopt another protocol 'A'.
If I adopt 'X' in another class 'Y', but try and declare the required property as a type that implements A, I get an the following error:

> Type 'Y' does not conform to protocol 'X'

Here is an example:

```
protocol A {

}

class B : A {
    var foo = "foo"
}

protocol X {
    var someA : A {get set}
}

class Y : X {  //Error: Type Y does not conform to protocol X
    var someA = B()
}
```

If I declare someA as A as follows:

```
var someA : A = B()
```

There is no error, but then I have would have to cast someA as B to access foo.

My question is why can I not declare someA as type B in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the protocol `X` states that `someA` is of type `A`, so in class `Y`, if you made `someA` of type `B`, then you couldn't assign anything of type `A` to it, which the protocol says that you need to be able to do.

If the protocol said that you needed a variable to hold any `Car`, and you had a `Porsche`, so you just wanted to tell your protocol conforming class that the variable could only hold a `Porsche`, then someone who comes along and tries to put a `Mazda` into your `Porsche` variable would encounter an issue, since the protocol says they should be able to.

Comment: You can find some more info about why this works how it does by looking at http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/type-variance-in-swift

Comment: and this blog https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html